# Как получить ссылку на страницу входа и регистрации в Django

Tags: python, django

Для регистрации пользователей я использую django-allauth.Так вот, вход происходит по адресу localhost:5000/accounts/login . В одном из шаблонов есть 2 кнопки: "Вход" и "Регистрация", шаблон отвечает за url localhost:5000/blog/post/. Как мне сделать в этих кнопках ссылку на Вход и Регистрацию

```
<li class="item button secondary">
    <a href="#"> Sign In </a>
</li>

<li class='item button'>
    <a href='#'> Sign Up </a>
</li>
```

Comment: `{% url 'account_login' %}`

Answer (score 0):

Используйте обычные url-теги, чтобы django автоматически выполнял реверс пути по его названию.

Например, чтобы отправить пользователя на страницу входа, используйте `{% url 'account_login' %}`, а для редиректа на страницу регистрации – `{% url 'account_signup' %}`.

Вы можете найти все нейминги путей в django-alluth в [официальной документации](https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/views.html)